# How to specify remote Windows path to synchronise with Linux local machine using "rsync"

Tags: command-line, ssh, windows, rsync

I have a local Ubuntu computer and a remote Windows computer. I need to sync folders on above two systems from Ubuntu command line (Terminal) using `rsync`

I‌ have `ssh` and `rsync` installed on my Ubuntu and `Bitvise SSH Server` installed on my Windows.

I can connect to my Windows command line using `ssh` command from Ubuntu terminal. Also I‌ can connect to my Ubuntu command line using `PuTTY` from my Windows computer.

I‌ used below command to sync folders on two computers:

```
rsync -av -e "ssh -l win_user -p 43" windowshost:"T:/" "/home/ubuntu_user/Documents/
```

It asks me for `win_user` password and after entering correct password it starts `receiving incremental file list` but returns following error:

```
rsync: change_dir "/c/Users/win_user/T:" failed: Bad file number (9)
```

Any one could help me to know how to tell `rsync` that select "T:" folder on Windows system?